# Extglob syntax style matching in Ruby

Tags: ruby, glob, extglob

I want to create a glob expression that recognises filenames that don't have any full stops (periods) in them, and use that expression within Ruby code. I realise that ordinary glob expressions can't do this. However, bash extglob has a syntax that can handle this. Is it possible to use a bash extglob style pattern in Ruby, either using core Ruby libraries, or third party gems?

I tried using `File::FNM_EXTGLOB`, but that didn't work. The following is a simplified scenario to test whether `File::FNM_EXTGLOB` has the exact same syntax as bash extglob, and it seems not to be the case:

```
File.fnmatch("myfile_+[0-9].txt", "myfile_123.txt", File::FNM_EXTGLOB)
```

Also, the [English-language](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) and [Japanese-language](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/File/s/fnmatch.html) documentation of `File.fnmatch` only talk about `File::FNM_EXTGLOB` allowing you to use a union of two possibilities such as `File.fnmatch('c{at,ub}s', 'cats', File::FNM_EXTGLOB)`.

Alternatives to using a glob expression would be to go to regular expressions, or possibly [using the operating system to do the globbing itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605380/globbing-using-braces-on-ruby-1-9-3#comment56956291_34605380), but I'd rather not go down those paths if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation that you linked to describes everything that can be done with `FNM_EXTGLOB` in Ruby; that is, the braces are the only extra functionality that you get while using that flag. Not sure if there are any external libraries but I doubt that there are.